# failed to build a release apk from ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I want to get apk from my Ionic v1 app, I get the error shown in the image below. Can anyone please help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the Android Studio installed?

Comment: @printfmyname No, I'm just install jdk and sdk

Comment: Looks like this is a fix to your issue. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/building-android-error-missing-gradle-wrapper/88116/2 .

Answer (score 0):

[here's](https://gradle.org/install/) a link to install Android gradle on your machine.
This is what you are missing, looking at your error logs.